# Can we ask questions about Safari 9?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Safari 9 is available for download for OS X Mavericks (10.9), Yosemite (10.10), and El Capitan (10.11), *if you are part of the Apple Developer Program*.

Can we ask questions about it?

Comment: If it's a programming question, I don't see why not.

Comment: OTOH, what use will it be in a couple years time when users are on Safari 12?

Comment: True.. but it may be of use now, while we use Safari 9, right? ;)